# Using HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression with WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

How to set `AutomaticDecompression` with using `WebApplicationFactory`?

The example API returns JSON with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

```cs
public class BasicTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_CurrectIdValue()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Needs to set AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        // Returns with Content-Encoding: gzip
        var actual = await client.GetJsonAsync<FooModel>("api/foo");

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal("1", actual.Id);
    }
}
```

> [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft
>   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by xneg - calling `WebApplicationFactory.CreateDefaultClient` with custom `DelegatingHandler` and `SocketsHttpHandler` as `InnerHandler` - does not work. It turns out that when `WebApplicationFactory` creates instance of `HttpClient`, it substitutes `InnerHandler` with instance of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler`. See the [code of CreateDefaultClient](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0c14ece1a347145f2be87c064ddaa56fa4bc6800/src/Mvc/Mvc.Testing/src/WebApplicationFactory.cs#L477) method for more details.

The best approach which worked for me is custom `DelegatingHandler` which performs decompression of content in `HttpResponseMessage`. The same logic is implemented by [DecompressionHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/DecompressionHandler.cs#L14) class and its private class [GZipDecompressedContent](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d5f40ecf8d645ced93c6ac954c4b0b42d8afb710/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/DecompressionHandler.cs#L209).
So, in order to reuse existing functionality and do the job with smallest possible code, I've used reflection for creating instance of `GZipDecompressedContent`:

```cs
public class DecompressionDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.LastOrDefault() == "gzip")
        {
            response.Content = CreateGZipDecompressedContent(response.Content);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static HttpContent CreateGZipDecompressedContent(HttpContent originalContent)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(HttpClient).Assembly;

        const string typeName = "System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler+GZipDecompressedContent";
        var gZipDecompressedContentType = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        if (gZipDecompressedContentType == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to find type '{typeName}'");
        }

        return (HttpContent)Activator.CreateInstance(gZipDecompressedContentType, originalContent);
    }
}
```

Then create instance of `HttpClient` via `CreateDefaultClient` method with above handler:

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = factory.CreateDefaultClient(new DecompressionDelegatingHandler());
```

I'm not happy with such solution because it uses non-public functionality from `System.Net.Http` assembly and it could break with the next update. The alternative could be implementing `HttpContent` decompression as it's done in [DecompressionHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/DecompressionHandler.cs#L14), but it will take quite a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do that is create your own `DelegatingHandler` and use inside it `SocketsHttpHandler` with settings you want. So it looks like that:

```
class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public MyHandler()
    {
        InnerHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
var client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(new MyHandler());
```

I think it is a bit ugly but should work.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work. When `WebApplicationFactory` creates `HttpClient`, it substitutes `InnerHandler` with instance of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler`.